# Solving $(f(x))^2 = f(\sqrt{2}x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

I would like to know how to solve this equation :

$$f(x)^2 = f(\sqrt{2}x)$$

We assume that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^{2}$.

The answer should be $f(x)=e^{-x^{2}/2}$, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: @AlexHalm that doesn't help ! I only get an even more complicated equation.

Comment: You take log and second derivatives on both sides and the resulting function on both sides satisfy $h(x)=h(2x)$. Therefore it is constant.

Comment: Btw you run into problems if $f(z) =0$, you may need to handle that case

Comment: @kennytm: I think you overwrote another condition, namely that $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\text dx=1$...

Comment: @abiessu I overwrote it.

Comment: How to handle the case $f=0$ ?

Comment: @Dark: explicitly state that $f(x)=0$ is an alternate solution, but which may or may not satisfy other conditions, such as $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\text dx=1$.

Comment: @abiessu yes, but how to show that in the other case $f$ is strictly positive ? (in order to be able to write $f = e^{g}$)

Comment: @Nathanson: this is not the only possibility. For any periodic function $p$ of period $1$, $h(x)=p(\log_2(x))=p(\log_2(2x))=h(2x)$.

Comment: @Dark: I've added a bit of argumentation to my answer in an effort to show that, but without additional constraints (like $f(x)\in\Bbb R$) I'm probably wrong...

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think we all assumed that $f$ is continuous and non 0 in $0$, thus $h(x) = h(x/2^n) \to h(0)$.

Comment: @Dark: with that edit to my answer, and assuming that there is no change in intent, I think we can write off negative possibilities for $f(x)$.

Comment: @abiessu: we already know that $f$ is non-negative. But what we need is $f$ to be strictly positive.

Comment: @Dark: ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  Having something like $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\text dx=1$ would do the trick, or something similar which forces at least one value of $f(x)$ to be non-zero.

Comment: Backing up a moment, I see that "the answer should be $f(x)=e^{-\frac {x^2}2}$", but we don't seem to have enough conditions on $f(x)$ to force that to be true.  Are there any conditions missing?

Comment: @abiessu yes the general answer is $f(x)=e^{\lambda x^{2}}$. We can add a condition on $f''(0)$ if we want to get $\lambda$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints :

- assume $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$
- write $g = \log f$
- apply the equality in $g$ twice to get a term $g(2x)$
- take the second derivative of the equality in $g$ and get $g(2x) = g(x)$
- conclude that $g''$ is constant

Additional notes :

- because $f(0)^2 =f(0)$, $f(0) \in \{0,1\}$
- if $\exists x \mid f(x)=0$, then $f(0)=0$ (because $f(x/\sqrt2) = \ldots = f(x/\sqrt2^n) = 0$ and $f$ is continuous in $0$
- as pointed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203970/follow-up-to-fx2-f-sqrt2-x/1203998#1203998), if $\exists a \mid f(a)>0$, $f(a/\sqrt{2}^k) = f(a)^{\frac1{2^k}}$ and $f(0)=1$ by continuity of $f$ in $0$

So either:

- $f(0) = 1$, and then $f$ is strictly positive and $f(x) = e^{\lambda x^2}$,
- or $f(0)=0$ and $f = 0$.

PS: as Yves' excellent post shows, relaxing the $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ assumption, even only in $0$, generates a wide class of additional solutions.

PPS: I've opened a new question to see what happens if we relax some of these conditions here: [$f(\alpha x) = f(x)^{\beta}$ under different constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205912/f-alpha-x-fx-beta-under-different-constraints)

Comment: Thank you. I conclude that $g''=0$ and so $g(x) = ax+b$ : this is not the answer. What did I miss ?

Comment: Thank you. So we can conclude that $f(x)=e^{\lambda x^{2}}$.

Comment: $g''$ constant is a possible solution but there are many others.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: not if we impose $g''$ continuous in $0$.

Comment: @AlexHalm: can you prove that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I did, in a comment to the main question. If $h = g''$ is continuous in $0$, then for any $x$, $h(x) = h(x/2) = \ldots = h(x/2^n) \to h(0)$.

Comment: @AlexHalm: Understood.

Answer (score 6):

Setting $x=2^{t/2}$ and taking the logarithm twice,
$$(f(x))^2=f(\sqrt2x)$$
becomes
$$\log_2(\log_2(f(2^{t/2})))+1=\log_2(\log_2(f(2^{(t+1)/2})))$$
or
$$h(t)+1=h(t+1).$$
An obvious solution is $h(t)=t+c$, or $\log_2(\log_2(f(2^{t/2})))=t+c=2\log_2(x)+c$, $$f(x)=2^{Cx^2}.$$

More solutions are found by adding smooth periodic functions of period $1$, like

$$h(t)=t+A\sin(2\pi t)+c,$$

that yield

$$f(x)=2^{Cx^22^{A\sin(4\pi\log_2(x))}}.$$

Example with $C=-1,A=1$:

[image]

Comment: Nice chart! You should probably highlight the derivability / positivity assumptions you're working on or the OP may become really confused

Comment: For $x<0$, I guess that the transform $x=-2^{t/2}$ works too and $f$ is an even function. I admit that derivability at $0$ should be scrutinized.

Comment: My gut feel is that the periodic term introduces a $1/x$ term in the derivative. Thinking in terms of the $h$ function from the comments above, if $h(x) = p(\log(x))$, then when $x\to 0$, $\log x \to -\infty$ and $h(x)$ oscillates without a limit.

Comment: Awesome answer. Definitely filing this trick away for future use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is it possible to show that $f$ is strictly positive in the first place ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: the best I can do with that is that $f(x)$ is non-negative, but so far I can't preclude $f(x)=0$...

Comment: @abiessu: Right, it is likely that there are solutions with $f(x)=0$ on part of the semi-octave and nonzero on the complement. This can be achieved with $h$ taking infinite values, and $C$ negative. There is a smell of $e^{-1/x}$ factors.

Answer (score 0):

With starting point $(f(x))^2=f(\sqrt 2x)$, we can get to $(f(x))^4 = f(2x)$ and further $(f(x))^{16}=f(4x)$ and so on, such that

$$(f(x))^{2^n}=f(\sqrt{2^n}x)$$

thus showing that our function passes constants in an exponential manner.  Then we take $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ and get

$$e^{2g(x)}=e^{g(\sqrt 2x)}$$

from which we can say that $2g(x)=g(\sqrt 2x)$ or $4g(x)=g(2x)$.  Taking the derivative here yields

$$4g'(x)=2g'(2x)\\
4g''(x)=4g''(2x)$$

At the point of this second derivative, we see that $g''(x)$ must be constant or periodic with period a multiple of $\sqrt 2$.  Working backwards, we must have $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ (for non-periodic solutions), and with $2g(x)=g(\sqrt 2x)$ we must in fact have $g(x)=ax^2$ (non-periodic solutions).  At this point in the process, there must be some other qualifier in order to get a single function $f(x)$ from the family

$$f(x)=e^{ax^2}$$

Caveat: $f(x)=0$ is also a possible solution not covered by the coefficient $a$ above.

Suppose that we consider $\exists x_0:f(x)\lt 0$.  Then we must have $(f(x_0/\sqrt 2))^2=f(x_0)\lt 0$, which means that $f(x_0/\sqrt 2)=0+qi$ for some real $q$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  But now we also get that $(f(x_0))^2=f(\sqrt 2x_0)\gt 0$ which leads us into our previous solution set where none of the values are negative, which is a contradiction; therefore our assumption that there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is negative must be false or else our derivation of the solution set incorrectly constrains the resulting set.  This would also mean that any solution containing non-real numbers cannot contain any real numbers.  Since one of the tags in this particular question says "real analysis" I will take that as a cue to say, having any negative result of $f(x)$ brings the function into complex analysis, and therefore such possibilities for $f(x)$ are beyond the scope of this question.