# Follow-up to $f(x)^2 = f(\sqrt2 x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

This is a follow-up to: [Solving $(f(x))^2 = f(\sqrt{2}x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203081/solving-fx2-f-sqrt2x/1203106#1203106) .

So $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is $\mathcal C^2$ and verifies $\forall x,\, f(x)^2 = f(\sqrt2 x)$.

We already know that $f(0) \in \{0,1\}$ and that if $f(0)=1$, $f$ is strictly positive and $f(x) = e^{\lambda x^2}$.

The question is: what if $f(0) = 0$? Specifically:

- are there solutions other than $0$?
- are there solutions where $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x\neq0)\neq0$?
- what would be generic descriptions of solutions with $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: an example would be to take $f=0$ except if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt 2\mathbb{Q}$ for which $f(x)=1$

Comment: @Elaqqad A continuous function that vanishes in the irrationals is identically zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f(a)=A\ne0$ for some $a\in{\mathbb R}$. Then $A=f^2\bigl({a\over\sqrt{2}}\bigr)>0$, and
$$f\left({a\over2^{n/2}}\right)=A^{1/2^n}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ we conclude that $f(0)=1$. You already have found out that in this case necessarily $f(x)=e^{\lambda x^2}$ for some $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$.

This shows that $f(0)=0$ leads to the sole solution $f(x)\equiv0$.

Comment: !!! Wow, that was incredibly silly. I even almost wrote it down myself!